# Passing JVM args to Docker image of Spring boot app on Kubernetes

Tags: java, docker, ssl, kubernetes, jvm

I am trying to pass JVM args to Docker image of Spring boot app on Kubernetes. Specifically, I wanted to pass these three arguments:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/certs/truststore/cacerts
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password
-Djavax.net.debug=ssl
```

I tried adding it to "env" section with name as "JAVA_OPTS", "JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS" and "JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS", none of which seemed like they were working.

I also tried adding it under "args" section, that did not work either. At best I get no change in behaviour at all, at worst my pods won't start at all with this error:

> Error: failed to create containerd task: OCI runtime create failed:
> container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused:
> process_linux.go:545: container init caused: setenv: invalid argument:
> unknown

Entry point in Dockerfile is defined as such:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app/appname-exec.jar"]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you read [official documentation](https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-boot-docker/)?

Comment: I haven't actually, Andrey. I had just realized at the end of my post that the issue is probably in the Docker image itself. Thank you, I will look into it.

Comment: I believe  smth. like `ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "java ${JAVA_OPTS} -jar /app/appname-exec.jar ${0} ${@}"]` is what you need.

Comment: (You shouldn't need to write `ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "..."]`; leave off the JSON-array wrapper and Docker will insert `sh -c` for you.)

Comment: Thanks David, I'm just looking at Dockerfile documentation and the alternative to JSON array wrapper that is used in exec form seems to be shell form. Is that it?

Comment: Hi @lovrodoe, any progress? Did you try to rebuild Docker image  with an entrypoint that supports JAVA_OPTS?

Answer (score 3):

To override the container's default `ENTRYPOINT` setting, I sometimes do the following:

```yaml
containers:
  - name: my-container
    image: mycontainer:latest
    command: ["java"]
    args: ["-Djavax...", "-Djavax...", "-jar", "myapp.jar"]
```

You can define content in the manifest that you would describe in a Dockerfile. In `args` section, you can describe as many settings as you want.

Comment: Looks promising, I will give this a go as soon as I can. Can you just clarify several things? a) I already have some args getting passed under args section prefixed with `--`, I assume those are program arguments. Can I move them to env block? As I understand, stuff from environment gets passed as program arguments. b) If I override this command, will my env vars still get passed as program arguments, or do I need to specify something additional in args? Hopefully my questions make sense, I'm quite new to both Docker and Kubernetes.

Comment: a) You can pass the extra arguments for your application (not for Java) by adding them at the end of the `args` section, like `args: [..., "-jar", "myapp.jar", "--args1", ...]`.
b)  I'm not sure if I understood, you mean that you already have the `env` section in your manifest? If so and your application is running, just keep them as they are.  the changes of `commands` and `args` won't affect on `env`.

Comment: Env section of my Kubernetes deployment manifest, yes. Thanks, this will be brilliant for testing, but I'm thinking I should really rebuild Docker images with an entry point that supports JAVA_OPTS.

Comment: Yes, if the application always needs these arguments, it should be on the Dockerfile.